# How can I cryptographically verify that someone owns the website they claim to?

Tags: security, https, cryptography, verification, x509

More specifically, can I get them to sign a string of text with their x509 private certificate and then I can verify it using the public cert used by the website in question? Perhaps I could supply them with an unsigned certificate for them to sign or something to that effect.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This would confirm ownership of a private key, not a website.  The best way to confirm ownership of the website would be to have them upload a file to it with agreed content.

Comment: The person with access to that private key would surly be the website owner/authority though I would hope :)

Comment: So the answer depends on your goal then?  You can't "cryptographically confirm they own the website", because someone else might have access to the private key other than the website owner.  The only way to confirm they own the website itself is to have them make an agreed change.  If they upload a file to the website, and you access it via https, then the file is being encrypted by their private key, and you are decrypting it with their public key.  It is the same process as if they did it by hand.

Comment: (I should point out that I went through most of the steps using openssl before I realised I was just doing what a webserver does)

Comment: I understand where you are coming from. I also realise that I am performing the same action as a server, much simpler to think of it that way thankfully :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as you suggested, you could send them a string of bytes ( in this context we might call it a challenge text) and have them encrypt it with their server's SSL/TLS private key and send back the ciphertext, then you can verify it by decrypting it with the public key from their SSL/TLS server cert.

Or you could generate a string of bytes, encrypt it with the public key from their server cert, send it to them, have them decrypt it with their server's private key, and have them send you back the original cleartext.

Note, though, that relatively few people know how to do things like this with their SSL private key, so don't be surprised if you have to provide them with step-by-step instructions for finding their private key and encrypting or decrypting your challenge.

Comment: Fantastic! Now, where might I find this guide you speak of? lol, I need to learn this :)

Comment: "man openssl" "man x509" "man rsa" "man enc" haha

Comment: lol, darn it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can have them send you an email from that domain, or do a whois (CLI or use https://www.whois.net/) and see if their contact is listed, or you can have them upload a verification page to their site. url/yeaIownthis.html with some password on it or something.

Comment: Much appreciated, that is definitely an option but if it can be done cryptographically I would much prefer it. Perhaps I could supply them with an unsigned certificate for them to sign?

Comment: Give me a scenario. Understand that the certificate authorities (ie VeriSign) that issue certificates do a lot of leg work to ensure the identities of the people that are issued certificates (extended validation cert's anyway. Domain certs are easy to get.) So you can trust that a person owns a website as long as they offer proof of identity to your own satisfaction. You cannot validate their certificate because you are not the issuer.

Comment: Why not just have them put something up on their web page? If you retrieve is using https, then it's cryptographic.

Comment: Here's a good explanation. http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/56389/ssl-certificate-framework-101-how-does-the-browser-actually-verify-the-validity

Comment: I'm trying to script it so I don't have to do it manually and a signed string or file seemed like the sensible thing for the user to submit. I was hoping I could know that they had access to the private x.509 by verifying against the public x.509 accessible through the website, using openssl or something along those lines.

Comment: http://giantdorks.org/alain/shell-script-to-check-ssl-certificate-info-like-expiration-date-and-subject/    ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method using M2Crypto and python:

```
f = open(CERT_FILE)
cert_buffer = f.read()
f.close()

from M2Crypto import RSA, X509 
cert = X509.load_cert_string(cert_<wbr>buffer, X509.FORMAT_PEM) 
pub_key = cert.get_pubkey() 
rsa_key = pub_key.get_rsa() 
cipher = rsa_key.public_encrypt('<wbr>plaintext', RSA.pkcs1_padding)

print cipher

ReadRSA = RSA.load_key(KEY_FILE)
try:
    plaintext = ReadRSA.private_decrypt (cipher, RSA.pkcs1_padding)
except:
    print "Error: wrong key?"
    plaintext = ""

print plaintext
```

Excerpt taken from [this](http://blog.richardknop.com/2012/08/create-a-self-signed-x509-certificate-in-python/) article.